# It is not clear how the function"GridSearchCV" breaks up the training and test sets

Tags: python, scikit-learn

It is not clear how the function"GridSearchCV" breaks up the training and test sets.
Total 67959 lines with signs.
By default, the function"train_test_split" splits into a training 75% and a test 25%.
In training 50969 and test 16990 lines with signs.
I print the length of the array y_pred in the function"T_scorer", it turns 5662.
Along the way, I print the matrix of confusion.
If you add all the elements from the matrix, you get about 16990.
It turns out the test set is once again divided into training and test sets.
What am I doing wrong?
I need to test the set was 16990, and training 50969.

```
[[ 763  891]
 [1216 2792]]
5662
[[2785  525]
 [1578 6440]]
11328
```

The value of the matrix of confusion

```
_scorer = make_scorer(T_scorer)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=42)
clf = RandomForestClassifier()
grid_searcher = GridSearchCV(clf, parameter_grid, verbose=20, scoring=_scorer)
grid_searcher.fit(X_test, y_test)
clf_best = grid_searcher.best_estimator_
print('Best params = ', clf_best.get_params())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, GridSearchCV does a 3-Fold validation, meaning it splits your data in 3 equal parts (1,2,3) and run the following sequence :

- train on 1,2 --> test en 3
- train on 2,3 --> test on 1
- train on 1,3 --> test on 2

You don't have to use the train-test split here : just provide the X_train,y_train to gridsearchCV and let it work

You can also look at the "cv" part of the doc : http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html

EDIT : here is the final code from the comments :

```
grid_searcher = GridSearchCV(clf, param_grid=parameter_grid, cv=StratifiedKFold(shuffle =True, random_state = 42))
```

Comment: Training set outputs 50969 lines. How to access the rest of 16990?   
And is it possible to make the sets separated into only two parts?

Comment: That's not what I meant : you should use train_test_split at all, and provide all your data (your 67959 lines) to gridsearchCV. It's gridsearch CV that will split the data

Comment: Note that you can't nor should separate your data in only 2 sets while doing hyperparameters optimisation, as it will quickly lead to overfitting on the test set. GridsearchCV is using K-fold to limit this issue

Comment: If I understand correctly, the GridSearchCV function , you need to transfer all the data, that is X,y? That is: grid_searcher.fit(X, y).                               The question arises of the data being mixed in the GridSearchCV function. Since in " train_test_split "I use"random_state=42"?

Comment: Indeed, you should do grid_searcher.fit(X, y). You can get more informations on K-fold in the documentation : http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html. random_state is just a seed to have the same "random" splits every time.

Comment: In that case, you should use a StratifiedKFold (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html). The way to use it with gridSearchCV is to pass it as argument : grid_searcher = GridSearchCV(clf, param_grid=parameter_grid, cv=StratifiedKFold(random_state = 42))

Comment: For binary or multi-class cases, grid-search uses StratifiedKFold by default.

Comment: @VivekKumar is right, it's the default. But I don't think you can set the random_state without adding the parameter explicitly

Comment: Where in "GridSearchCV" is "random_state", I have not found in settings.

I got the impression that the data is still not mixed by default.

When explicitly specified "random_state=42", there was a significant difference before and after.
I really need to mix the data.